# SqlDataReader Datatype Conversion Error

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion, sqldatareader, datareader

I am trying to load items from database in combobox but in code this unexpected error came and there seems to be no apparent reason. Please help.
**Error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'**. 
In database, the datatype of 'PortName' is Varchar.

[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a39r1.png)

```
void FillCombo()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(global::flight_management.Properties.Settings.Default.conn);
        string sql = "SELECT PortName FROM PORTS";
        SqlCommand exesql = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
       try
        {
            conn.Open();
            myReader = exesql.ExecuteReader();
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                string sName = myReader.GetString("PortName");
  // ERORR HERE: Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'
                ComboFromA.Items.Add("sName");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {lblError.Text = "Error Loading Airports: "+ ex.Message;}
        finally {conn.Close();}
    }
```

[Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiocX.png)

Comment: I've noticed from your code there appears to have a distinct mix of responsibilities in it. It is not best practice to have data access in a method which also is creating the items in a combobox for the UI. It maybe just pure example code, but still, something to think about :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database types are important when reading data from SqlDataReader

ColumnType is String **GetString**

ColumnType is int    **GetInt32**

ColumnType is Double **GetDouble**

you can use the one as the example
I think this is the Best practice read value from `SqlDataReader`

```
myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("PortName"));
```

And replace

```
ComboFromA.Items.Add("sName") to ComboFromA.Items.Add(sName);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
void FillCombo()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(global::flight_management.Properties.Settings.Default.conn);
        string sql = "SELECT PortName FROM PORTS";
        SqlCommand exesql = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
       try
        {
            conn.Open();
            myReader = exesql.ExecuteReader();
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                string sName = myReader.GetString(0);
  //ust use the index 0 for first attribute in select list 
                ComboFromA.Items.Add("sName");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {lblError.Text = "Error Loading Airports: "+ ex.Message;}
        finally {conn.Close();}
    }
```